# removing 'rainy day' code from a C project

Tags: c

I have started a new job and inherited a project which contains a lot of 'rainy day' code by which I mean code which is never called.

Functions which are not referenced by higher lever ones and functions which contain code that can can never be executed.

Also header files containing

```
#define SomethingThatIsNotRefferenced  AsSomeValueUnused
```

Are there any tools to locate and remove this code?

An alternative is to remove sections with:

```
#if 0

   /* Some code */

#endif
```

To see what breaks it but obviously this is an iterative process.

Comment: Check out `--print-gc-sections` in `man ld`, I guess it should help you automate the process of identifying the unused functions.

Comment: Eyeballs and a sixth sense can help.  Using a tool like `cscope` or an IDE equivalent to it can help track uses.  You won't eliminate unused function declarations etc from system headers.  (I deal with this constantly — using eyeballs and `cscope`, mostly.  Only yesterday, I eliminated a function that was abusing a structure element and I couldn't see a way to fix it, so I went to see where it was used, but it wasn't still used.  It probably was used 20 years ago, but not any more.  Scratch that compiler warning by scratching the function that caused it.)

Comment: [gcov](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-Intro.html) could be an useful tool for your questions

Comment: If there are any functions that are not declared in header files, add the `static` qualifier to them and your compiler should warn you when they're not being used. That should help in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC and clang support a `-Wunused-function` warning (or just `-Wunused` if you also want to know about other stuff like unused variables and parameters).

*Edit*: I thought this worked across compilation units (with some caveats), but based on Jonathan Leffler's comments on this post, it looks like it doesn't.  It's still helpful so I'll leave the answer in place, but it might be better to take a look at something like [callcatcher](https://github.com/caolanm/callcatcher).

Comment: Is that for unused static functions in a single translation unit or does it somehow work across translation units when the linking is done?  I’m familiar with it for static functions; I’m not aware of it working across translation units. (It is bundled as part of either `-Wall` or `-Wextra` for static functions, IIRC. Certainly, I see it at work with those.)

Comment: I believe it works across translation units but only if you're compiling an executable, and you may need to enable LTO; for a library it has to assume that the unused functions are entry points.  I think it will also work for libraries for functions with hidden visibility.

Comment: Preliminary experimentation with GCC 9.1.0 on macOS 10.14.5 Mojave using `-Wunused-function -flto -g -O3` (and multiple other options) and listing a file containing a function `boondoggle()` that never existed until listed as one component of the build did not report that the function was unused (but it was present in the executable).

Comment: Interesting, thanks for testing!  Did you happen to test with -fvisibility=hidden (and `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` on the functions you want exposed)?  I'm pretty sure I've seen compiler warnings about unused non-static functions somewhere…

Comment: No extra attributes were used.